# Amazon SQS Message Attributes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am unable to properly add attributes. I'm using AWS 1.7
When I add them, they show in the message body, not the attributes. I can see this when I login to the AWS console.

I add the message attributes with this code:

```
                Message awsMessage = new Message();         

    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> messageAttributes = 
new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();

                messageAttributes.put("email", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withDataType("String")
                .withStringValue(email));
                messageAttributes.put("data", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withDataType("String")
                .withStringValue(newFileName));
                messageAttributes.put("template", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withDataType("String")
                .withStringValue(filename));

                awsMessage.setMessageAttributes(messageAttributes);
```

I tried using this to pull out the attributes:

```
List<Message> messages = SQSUtilityClass.getMessagesFromQueue(QUEUE_URL);
    int size = messages.size();
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    System.out.println("Size: "+size);
    for(int x =0;x<size;x++){
        Message message = messages.get(x);
        //System.out.println(message.getBody());
        attributes = message.getAttributes();
        for(String key: attributes.keySet()){
            System.out.println(key + " - "+ attributes.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Still, my attributes are in the message body when I view via AWS console.

Answer (score 4):

First. You need to specify what attributes do you want to receive with message. The following code will receive attributes `email`, `data` and `template` (as in your example):

```
final AmazonSQS sqs = // your code to get SQS instance
final String queue = // queue url
final List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(
    new ReceiveMessageRequest(queue)
        .withMessageAttributeNames("email", "data", "template")
).getMessages();
```

Second. You should use `message.getMessageAttributes()` instead of `message.getAttributes()`:

```
final String email =
    message.getMessageAttributes().get("email").getStringValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library to produce to SQS.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
      <version>${aws-messaging-lib-version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

Here is a sample code to produce.

```
    SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest();
    request.withMessageAttributes(mapMessageAttributes(messageAttributes));
    request.setMessageBody(message);
    request.setQueueUrl(queueUrl);
    sqsClient.sendMessage(request);
```

where mapMessageAttributes(messageAttributes) returns a Map and sqsClient is an instance of AmazonSQSClient.

Once the attributes are delivered to SQS, i am using the JMS library to consume by setting them up as a Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

```
        SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
                        .withRegion(AWSSQSUtils.getAWSRegion(region))
                        .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                        .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(prefetchCount)
                        .withClientConfiguration((new ClientConfiguration())
                                .withMaxConnections(connectionsCount)
                                .withProxyHost(proxyHost)
                                .withProxyPort(proxyPort))
                        .build();

        LOG.info("Connection factory initialized..");

        // Create the connection.
        SQSConnection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Create the transacted session with UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE mode.
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue immediateQueue = session.createQueue(safInputQueueImmediate);
        Queue normalQueue = session.createQueue(safInputQueueNormal);

        LOG.info("Connection established and session created..");

        //Create listeners
        immediateListnerContainer = new
                DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        immediateListnerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        immediateListnerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(consumerConcurrency);
        immediateListnerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        immediateListnerContainer.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER);
        immediateListnerContainer.setDestination(immediateQueue);
        immediateListnerContainer.setMessageListener(
                new StoreAndForwardListener(jobService, persistentMessagingDao));
        immediateListnerContainer.setMaxMessagesPerTask(maxMessagesPerTask);
        immediateListnerContainer.afterPropertiesSet();
        immediateListnerContainer.start();
```

I am using programmatic approach vs. declarative because SQS supports unordered aknowledge, which is not supported by Spring JMS yet.

In the onMessage method of the MessageListener, you will be handed a javax.jms.Message object, which can get used to get all the message attributes as shown below.

```
Enumeration<String> headers = message.getPropertyNames();
while(headers.hasMoreElements()){
   attributeName = headers.nextElement();
   print(message.getStringProperty(attributeName))
}
```

Hope that helps.

I do have a ticket open with AWS, where some attributes are getting dropped in transit. i.e i set M number of attributes and only M-1 or M-2 attributes make it to SQS. As soon as i have an update, i will add it here.